# how to sort a list according to a specific field in one line? (in java)

Tags: java, sorting

Given a list (ArrayList), containing items from a specific class (also given, called "Point"), how can I sort the list according to a specific field(of type int) in Point class (only the x-dimension)?

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851980/using-the-sort-function-to-sort-a-list-according-to-a-function), and I know the function: Collections.sort(list_name, new comperator_name) usually works - but I cannot change the class point or change anything other than one line in the main function.

Two solutions would be appreciated: one for a point class without "compare" or "compareTo" functions, and one with a "compare" function.

Edit: for some reason someone suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) as a duplicate - and I saw it before, but specifically asked for a solution that does not need to implement a comperator.

Comment: You do realize the linked question / answer is for a different programming language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: The questions are very related... But in this one he is specifically asking for the answer to be one line of code. I don't think it is exactly the same question. Anyway, check my answer... I think it solves your problem

Comment: luk2302 I am aware, and still found it helpful to show that I researched these ideas and did not find them helpful.
JornVernee Why is everyone here in a hurry to downvote and mark duplicate? I specifically asked NOT to use a comperator - so no, a case using a comperator is different from a case not using it.
LeandroBorgesFerreira Thank you - you're the real MVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Java 8 List has

```
List.sort(Comparator<? super E> c).
```

And the Comparator has:

```
comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

So you can do you can use use

```
List.sort(Comparator.comparing(Point::someField))
```

Java 8 had many updates in the Collections package, so now you have many new methods and you can use to make your code thiner... Like sort a list with just one line.

Have fun!

Read here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

And here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

For more info about Comparator an List in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
List.sort(Comparator<? super E> c).
```

add the comparator then

```
comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

and then finally use

```
List.sort(Comparator.comparing(Point::someField))
```